# Do I need separate SKProduct for subscription with and without trial? [AppStore]

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

I am setting up auto-renewable subscriptions for my app.

I have set up 4 subscriptions for 1,3,6, and 12 months with a one week free trial.

Works like a charm, everything is displayed properly on device, etc.

But now I need to take into account multiple cases and one of them is when the user has already consumed the free trial, cancelled the subscription, and then is about to subscribe again.

I don't want to present "1 Week Free Trial" on the payment screen and certainly I don't want the user, who has already used the trial, to be eligible to use it again.

So the question is if I need 2 sets of subscriptions in total?

With Trial:

- my_app_1_month_trial
- my_app_3_months_trial
- my_app_6_months_trial
- my_app_12_months_trial

And without trial:

- my_app_1_month
- my_app_3_months
- my_app_6_months
- my_app_12_months

And then, when user has already used the free trial (this piece of information will be either fetched from my server or an apple receipt), I use the SKProducts from the "without trial" set and the user is charged immediately.

Comment: You can check the receipt to see if they have ever subscribed before in order to customise the message you show. Then you can use a single set of products

Comment: But it is Apple who shows the "1 Week Trial" on the payment screen. Do they always show that, but upon purchase it is actually validate if the user has already used the trial and if so, the user is charged immediately?

Comment: Yes, Apple knows whether they have already received the free trial and will adjust the purchase screen.  You must ensure that all of the subscriptions are in the same product group so that only one free trial can be redeemed across all durations

Comment: Yep, they are. OK, so I am all good.